# HQL Join with many conditions

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I've got two relations: Position(idPosition, ...), History(idHistory, idPosition, date, type) and I'd like to translate this SQL query into HQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Position 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Hisotry 
ON Position.idPosition = History.idPosition 
AND History.date = '2015-02-03' AND History.type = 7
WHERE History.date IS NULL
```

for me it should look like this:

```
SELECT * from Position p
LEFT OUTER JOIN p.History h 
WITH h.date = '2015-02-03' AND h.type = 7
WHERE h.date IS NULL
```

however HQL won't let me do WITH clause with two conditions. When I do this I get exception:

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements`

Can somebody tell me how to translate this SQL into correct HQL query? My hibernate version is 4.3.6

Comment: How come in your where your are filtering to get only `date is null` data and in join you are matching with date value ? Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679908/hibernate-hql-how-to-use-a-complex-left-join-fetch

Comment: If left outer join doesn't find for position corresponding entry in history, it will add to this position history columns filled with nulls.